# ngModel binding not working in page section

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I have a peculiar issue with `[(ngModel)]` not binding two ways in a particular section on a page. In the section where the binding is not working, adding the binding makes other text within the `div` disappear from the `DOM`.

```
<div>
  <div>

    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test" />
//Works here
 {{test}}

  </div>


 <div>
//Not working here and other text disappears
 Other text here {{test}}

 </div>
</div>
```

Any pointers on how to investigate this further?

Comment: It does work: [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ef1pqt) your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: It should work as there is no error in your code shown, for sure error must be somewhere else

Comment: Any console error...?

Answer (score 0):

//app.module.ts

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ]